# Accessing data in Tooltip on D3 Multi-line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Here is my data.

```
var data = [
    {
        "label": "branch-1",
        "values": [
            { "day": "Monday", "value": 20},
            { "day": "Tuesday", "value": 18},
            { "day": "Wednesday", "value": 29},
            { "day": "Thursday", "value": 31},
            { "day": "Friday", "value": 37},
            { "day": "Saturday", "value": 25},
            { "day": "Sunday", "value": 19}
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "branch-2",
        "values": [
            { "day": "Monday", "value": 32},
            { "day": "Tuesday", "value": 29},
            { "day": "Wednesday", "value": 37},
            { "day": "Thursday", "value": 41},
            { "day": "Friday", "value": 31},
            { "day": "Saturday", "value": 28},
            { "day": "Sunday", "value": 17}
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to add label into tooltip, however get the error "undefined". I also need to append labels end of the each line. Similary, names in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) example. But i can't find how to achieve this.

Fiddle link for my code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mQMH3/).

Comment: Updated the answer to include addition of labels at end of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the label in the tooltip you would need to have label name in individual data points:

Modify data processing block as follows:

```
data.forEach(function (kv) {
    var labelName = kv.label;
    kv.values.forEach(function (d) {
        d.value = +d.value; 
        d.label = labelName;
    });
});
```

For adding the labels add following section:

```
city.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { var dayExt = d.values[d.values.length - 1].day; var valueExt = d.values[d.values.length - 1].value;  return "translate(" +  x(dayExt) + "," + y(valueExt) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.label });
```

Please find the complete fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/prashant_11235/LY8zt/

You may style the label names appropriately as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer prashant. I modified my code and now I can access labels. But how can I append this label end of the each line?

Comment: Added the block for adding labels to individual lines.

Comment: I also noted that you simply added my earlier block in the fiddle. It was meant to modify the block that you already had. Please refer my fiddle for updated code.